# How can I get the Facebook friends of a visiting user who hasn't installed my application?

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

I'm using the latest [PHP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP) [SDK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_development_kit) and have tried

```
$facebook->('/me/friends?fields=installed')
```

and it tells me I require an access token.

I tried `$facebook->getUser()`, and I get zero even though I am logged into Facebook.

I'm thinking that I figure out a user's friends who are on the application if I have the user's Facebook ID or with the `fields=installed` method.

Is there an easier way? If not, why am I having trouble getting the ID?

Comment: I would have thought it would be an entirely deliberate thing to restrict access to such data to only pre-authorised applications.

Comment: _“If not, why am I having trouble getting the ID?”_ – because you did not have the user _connect_ to your app first, I’d guess.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It turns out this can be accomplished rather trivially with a "Facepile". See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/facepile/

Comment: That shows it to the user, but you can't retrieve the details